Postgres with row level security does not optimize queries / uses one-time filters
It seems that postgres with enabled row level security on a table cannot properly optimize queries. The following example sql demonstrates the issue:
begin transaction;
    -- create demo table
    create table entries (id int primary key);

    -- setup rls
    alter table entries enable row level security;
    create policy entries_policy on entries for all using (
        current_setting('app.can_read_entries')::boolean = true
    );

    -- setup a role which cannot bypass rls
    create role authenticated;
    grant usage on schema public to authenticated;
    grant select on all tables in schema public to authenticated;

    -- configure setting (just as an example for a query condition)
    set local app.can_read_entries = true;
rollback;

When not using RLS:
explain
select * from entries
where (
    -- Simulate RLS query as superuser which bypasses RLS by adding the RLS condition manually
    current_setting('app.can_read_entries')::boolean = true
);

-- Result  (cost=0.01..35.51 rows=2550 width=4)
--   One-Time Filter: (current_setting('app.can_read_entries'::text))::boolean
--   ->  Seq Scan on entries  (cost=0.01..35.51 rows=2550 width=4)

whereas with row level security it will be
-- switch to 'authenticated' role to use rls in queries
set local role 'authenticated';

-- run the query with rls inlining its conditions
explain
select * from entries;

-- Seq Scan on entries  (cost=0.00..54.63 rows=1275 width=4)
--   Filter: (current_setting('app.can_read_entries'::text))::boolean

In the first query without rls, the optimizer properly recognizes, that the condition is static for the query and extracts it as a One-Time Filter check.
But the second query, where the condition is provided by rls does not get fully optimized and postgres will evaluate the condition for every row, even though it is constant for the whole query.
In this example, there's not much data and the query is simple, however it demonstrates the issue quite easily and the same behavior can be observed in tables with lots of data and indices etc. A more elaborate example is described here: https://pastebin.com/iQu6L5Sj
I already read about the leakproof attribute on functions and tried setting the leakproof attribute on current_setting and even went and tried update pg_proc set proleakproof = true;.
However, no matter what I try, postgres will not properly optimize the query with row level security.

EDIT: Another example which does not use a function like current_setting:
-- additionally create a users table
create table users (id int primary key);
-- and then use this policy
create policy entries_policy on entries for all using (
    exists (select 1 from users where id = 1)
    -- current_setting('app.can_read_entries')::boolean = true
);

Without RLS it will run as
Result  (cost=8.17..43.67 rows=2550 width=4)
  One-Time Filter: $0
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Only Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=0)
          Index Cond: (id = 1)
  ->  Seq Scan on entries  (cost=8.17..43.67 rows=2550 width=4)

and with RLS it will directly perform the sequence scan instead of using early-return:
Seq Scan on entries  (cost=8.17..43.67 rows=1275 width=4)
  Filter: $0
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Only Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=0)
          Index Cond: (id = 1)


What is your definition of optimize ? Your table is empty and you didn't share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) so we can't see any problem anyway.


Use EXPLAIN ANALYZE. 2) The queries are different in that the first has a WHERE and the second does not. 3) Both queries do a Seq Scan.


Again use EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Also include the query you used to generate the EXPLAIN output. Also the number of rows in the table is small there really is no optimization to be done

@AdrianKlaver The explain query used is in the example sql. at the bottom.
And yes, the table is empty in this case, but even the empty table is enough to already show the problem. Adding data & indices to it or using more complex queries will still result in the same behavior of the optimizer not extracting static conditions from RLS queries.


You changed the condition for how the RLS is done and the sample queries you show are for the previous condition. If you have any hope of getting an answer you need to provide a self contained example that shows a consistent series of steps. 2) The point of the planner is to shape the plan to the table contents. Running against an essentially empty table is not a realistic case.


@AdrianKlaver I think this might not have been clear, but the first query is running as superadmin and therefore ignoreing RLS. That is why I inserted the condition the RLS query would use manually.
The second query then runs with "authenticated" role which uses RLS so there I omitted the query.

What rows in your table entries should be accessible by the role authenticated  and why? And there are no rows at all, so a sequential scan is the best plan to execute the query.

@FrankHeikens I updated the description to explain it a bit better. Of course a seq scan is the fastest solution here. But the problem is rather that rls NEEDS to do a seq scan, where without rls it will completely skip the seq scan because of query optimization. THe code is just a minimal reproduction example and of course not the real world case

Yes, queries using row level security won't be optimized as well as queries without. PostgreSQL will only perform optimizations that it knows are safe. Because the optimizer's reasoning capabilities are limited, that will sometimes mean that it chooses a plan that won't be perfect.
In your special case, the queries will perform almost the same in the case where the user is allowed to see the data. But there is a difference in the "forbidden" case: the RLS query will still scan the table. Your problem is that the cast from text to boolean, which is performed using the type input function boolin(), is not leakproof.

Yeah, they WILL do the same, but with a huge impact on performance in certain scenarios. For example even a simple count(*) query can run on an index near instantly without rls, but will require a seq scan with rls. That's a huge impact imho.
I guess this means rls is not usable at all for our case.
FYI: I'm developing an application on supabase and it essentially only relies on RLS to manage all access permissions. That means I will have to ditch that whole stack and switch to a full api layer  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Are you saying that the plans actually perform differently? Could you edit the question and add EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) output for such queries?

@olee. This is the first time you mentioned you are using supabase, that would be something you really need to add to your question.
